# Skip the second scenario if the first scenario fails in Python Behave

Tags: python, bdd

I am writing a python behave script with feature file as input. Is it possible to skip the second scenario if the first scenario fails ? I know that usually the scenario's are independent but in my situation, this is necessary. Please let me know.

Comment: You should show your code because the terms you are using are not conventional.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to hazard a guess, what you are looking for is exception handling.

```
try:
    print (float('5.5'))
    print (float('eee')) #this will fail and lead to Exception
    print (float('13.5'))
except Exception as e:
    print (f'{type(e)}: {e}')

#Output: 
#5.5
#<class 'ValueError'>: could not convert string to float: 'eee'
```